# I can't get touchscreen working in CentOS 7 on an EP121 Tablet

Tags: centos, touch-screen, tablet

I just did a fresh install of CentOS 7 on my Asus EP121 tablet. The EP121 has touch and pen input.

During the install process the GUI install had working touch, much to my surprise.

After the install, X did not have working touch, but it seems to have Pen Input. ( or at least configuration software for wacom ). Unfortunately my pen is broken.

I have tried to install the egalax driver from ( http://www.eeti.com.tw/drivers_Linux.html ) which I read would work. Unfortunate it did not. In X I get the error egalax daemon not started when running the egalax software.

Since the touch input was working during install, I assume that the egalax driver is not really needed.

This is the output of xinput list | grep 'id='

```
Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Wacom ISDv4 90 Pen stylus                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    eGalax_eMPIA Technology Inc. PCAP MultiTouch Controller   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    eGalax_eMPIA Technology Inc. PCAP MultiTouch Controller   id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Wacom ISDv4 90 Pen eraser                 id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]

Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    USB 2.0 Camera                            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    NOVATEK USB NETVISTA FULL WIDTH KEYBOARD  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    NOVATEK USB NETVISTA FULL WIDTH KEYBOARD  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This is the output of lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5122 IMC Networks 2M Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011    Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0461:4e04 Primax Electronics, Ltd
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 056a:0090 Wacom Co., Ltd TPC90
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0eef:a001 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd
```

How do I get touchscreen working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the eGalax driver install

I added the line

```
/bin/eGTouchD
```

to the /etc/rc.local file

I also had to do a

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

To get it working.